# Representation theory of $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

[image]My question could appear naive but I am reading up representation theory by myself. I am at a loss to understand the way how the action of the matrix happens for $S_3$. For example how does each of these representation work on the vectors $(e_1 -e_2)$ and $(e_2 -e_3)$ is unclear.

The text says that $$(1, 2) (e_1-e_2)  = -(e_1 - e_2)$$ and $$(1, 2) (e_2 - e_3) = (e_1 - e_3).$$ How does one derive from the matrix action on the vector $(e_1, -e_2)$ and $(e_2, -e_3)$.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Where did you take this from? It doesn't look correct. For instance, the action of $(1\ \ 2)$ on $e_1-e_2$ should give $-2e_1-e_2$, not $-e_1+e_2$.

Comment: I will add the link of the place where I got from. Please look at pg 6 and pg 7 of the text. https://jdc.math.uwo.ca/M9140a-2012-summer/Diaconis.pdf

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Why? It seems that elements of $S_3$ act by permuting the basis, so, indeed, $(1 2)(e_1 - e_2) = (1 2)e_1 - (1 2)e_2 - e_2 - e_1 = - (e_1 - e_2)$.

Comment: @lisyarus I am surely missing something. Where did you read that $(1\ \ 2)$ permutes the basis? What I read is that $(1\ \ 2)e_1=-e_1$ and that $(1\ \ 2)e_2=e_1+e_2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos You are right, I didn't notice the explicit matrices given. Then, probably, $e_i$ and $w_i$ are different things?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I followed the link: yes, $e_i$ is the basis of the original 3-dimensional space, where $S_3$ acts by permuting the basis, while $w_i=e_i-e_{i+1}$ is the basis of the 2-dimensional irreducible subspace.

Comment: @lisyarus I only saw the link now.

Answer (score 4):

Since$$(1\ \ 2)e_1=e_2,\ (1\ \ 2)e_2=e_1\text{, and }(1\ \ 2)e_3=e_3,$$it is clear that$$(1\ \ 2)(e_1-e_2)=e_2-e_1=-(e_1-e_2)\text{ and that }(1\ \ 2)(e_2-e_3)=e_1-e_3.$$So, if we define $w_1$ and $w_2$ as $e_1-e_2$ and as $e_2-e_3$ respectively, we get that $(1\ \ 2)w_1=-w_1$ and that$$(1\ \ 2)w_2=e_1-e_3=e_1-e_2+e_2-e_3=w_1+w_2.$$Therefore, the matrix of the action of $(1\ \ 2)$ on $\bigl\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\,|\,x+y+z=0\bigr\}$ with respect to the basis $\{w_1,w_2\}$ is indeed$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$